# sql statement in PHP doesn't update the Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I put a number myself the database gets updated to Success but when I try to access the same number from $_POST It complete the transaction but doesn't affect the rows even thought it's using the same number.

Example of a query that works perfectly and updates the database

```
$sql = "UPDATE `transactions` SET `status` ='Success' WHERE `transactions`.`txn_id` = 65765756";
```

Example of a query that doesn't work

```
$sql = "UPDATE `transactions` SET `status` ='Success' WHERE `transactions`.`txn_id` = ".$_POST['m_payment_id'];
```

Comment: What does `echo $sql;` show?

Comment: I don't use the browser I receive a post request from a bank where the php file gets executed to modify the database@kmoser

Comment: I think you're missing my point: what is the exact SQL statement? Can you log that somewhere for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 2):

First, check what's in the value, and make sure it is the same as what you are manually entering.

`var_dump($_POST['m_payment_id'])`

Second, the code without any other checks is a SQL injection vulnerability.

You could convert the value into an integer to protect against this, e.g. `intval($_POST['m_payment_id'])`

Ideally though, you would be using [bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).